# Determine currently selected text

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications

This code is inside a subclass of NSWindowController:

```
@objc func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Show the previous (not current) selection range
    if let stuff = notification.userInfo {
        var i = 0
        for (key, value) in stuff {
            print("\(i) key=\(key) value=\(value)")
            i += 1
        }
    }
}

override func windowWillLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(self.textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)),
        name: NSTextView.didChangeSelectionNotification,
        object: nil)
}
```

The values of the two dictionary entries in the notification provide a range corresponding to the previous text selection.  How to know the current text selection when the notification is issued?

Comment: Also, with multiple NSTextFields, how to know for which the notification is begin issued?

Answer (score 0):

The text view (`NSTextView`) is the object of the notification. The text field is the delegate of the text view.

Comment: Thanks.  But it is really strange that this notification only gives information about the previous (not current) selection range in an NSTextField.  It is one selection step behind.  I don't understand why Apple would set it up this way.

Comment: You can get the current selection from the text view.

Answer (score 0):

If "notes" is an NSTextField, then this gives the current selected range:

```
        if let sr = notes.currentEditor()?.selectedRange {
            Swift.print("sr = \(sr.location) \(sr.length)")
        }
```

Very difficult to discover this via available documentation.

Comment: ln `textViewDidChangeSelection`, `notification.object` is the text view.